# Trying to implement a criteria query using Hibernate, getting "cannot resolve method" error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a table with the following columns and the corresponding POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "base_quote")
public class BaseQuote {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "cc_min")
private int cubicCapacityMin;

@Column(name = "cc_max")
private int cubicCapacityMax;

@Column(name = "car_age_min")
private int carAgeMin;

@Column(name = "car_age_max")
private int carAgeMax;

@Column(name = "base_amount")
public double baseAmount;
```

constructor, getters and setters

I am trying to write a query that will return the baseAmount for a car, the cubic capacity of which is between cc_min and cc_max and age is between carAgeMin and carAgeMax.  I am trying to get either the entire row so I can later use the baseAmount of that row.

I am receiving the cc and age of the car trough a DTO.

```
private double baseAmount (QuoteDTO quoteDTO) {
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<BaseQuote> cq = cb.createQuery(BaseQuote.class);
        Root<BaseQuote> root = cq.from(BaseQuote.class);
        cq.select(root).where(cb.gt(root.get("cc_max")), quoteDTO.getCubicCapacity());

        Query<BaseQuote> query = session.createQuery(cq);
        List<BaseQuote> results = query.getResultList();
      
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

I am getting something wrong because  I get cannot resolve method for `cb.gt(root.get("cc_max")` I tried also using the class field name `cubicCapacityMax` instead of `cc_max`, but I an getting the same error. I want to get the rows in which the  `cc_max` is greater than the DTO cubic capacity, so I used the `.gt()` as proposed in the demo I was using.  It underlines everything in the brackets of the `.gt()`. I know that this does not produce the specific result I am actually looking for, but it is the first part of the expression.  Where am I wrong?
[image]

Comment: You statement should be `cb.gt(root.get("cc_max"), quoteDTO.getCubicCapacity())`?

Comment: @samabcde I think so, I think the .gt() needs to compare what is in the database with the second parameter which in my case is an integer coming from the DTO. I think I am trying to read the cc_max incorrectly, but do not know why

Comment: Should you use mapped property `cubicCapacityMax` instead of column name `cc_max` as you are not writing sql? I suggest you to provide details of your new problem in another question, as the current question is just due to a simple typo.

Comment: You must use the property name, not the db field name: `root.get("cubicCapacityMax")` instead of `root.get("cc_max")`. Try to follow a "Hello World" tutorial and get it work, before posting a question

Comment: thank you both, I will edit my question accordingly, but as I said I tried using both cubicCapacityMax and cc_max and I got the same from IntelliJ

Comment: @kalina199 What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK I am using Hibernate5, at least that is the import in my HibernateConfig class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because using [`Path#get(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get-java.lang.String-) is not type-safe. Use Metamodel expressions if you want the compiler to correctly interpret the type you want to be returned.
If you use string parameter, you need to specify the type like that:

```
Expression<Integer> expr = root.<Integer> get("cubicCapacityMax");
```

Using Metamodel, the same expression could be obtained in this way:

```
Expression<Integer> expr = root.get(BaseQuote_.cubicCapacityMax);
```

Also note that the string parameter must correspond to the name of a property (`cubicCapacityMax` in this case) and not to the db name of the field (`cc_max`).

**See also:**

- [Oracle's Java EE Tutorial - Using the Criteria API and Metamodel API to Create Basic Typesafe Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)